# Htaccess code redirects to XAMPP index page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to write htaccess codes which redirect all URLs apart from directly linked files (e.g images & css files) to my index.php file for processing

```
http://localhost/testsite/login
```

redirects to

```
http://localhost/testsite/index.php?cmd=login
```

But the htaccess code instead redirects me to the XAMPP homepage. This is my htaccess code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?cmd=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `RewriteBase /testsite/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/` from target and use proper `RewriteBase`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testsite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?cmd=$1  [QSA,L]
```

`/index.php` will route it to site root `index.php` instead of `index.php` in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

That wont work simple go to your httpd.conf file and paste this

Alias /portfolio C:/xampp/htdocs/portfolio

```
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/portfolio>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /portfolio/

   RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Change the portfolio to your project folder

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code as your answers here, explain with some details why this is the optimal solution.